# C# Creating Folder on currently logged on Windows User as System Service

Tags: c#, windows, service, system

Is it possible to create a folder on the currently logged in Windows User's Desktop using a Service which runs as a System-Service?

Comment: Thx sir, may u tell me how? Ty

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I totally agree with that but I asked the question bcuz a colleague asked me the same question and I couldn't answer it. In the other hand I'm interested in Windows services but I've never worked with em in any way... I not even know how to debug a service - all though I'm interested.  So if you want to help me by posting a little snippet I'd be very thankful - and if not I'd understand you, too. Maybe you know a good tut for starting in services? Sorry for that bad English, it's pretty late